# Creating single JSON record from multiple JSON records (Performance efficient coding practice)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a dictionary with multiple JSON lines, as below.

```
my_dict = [{'processId': 'p1', 'userId': 'user1', 'reportName': 'report1', 'threadId': '12234', 'some_other_keys': 'respective values.12234'}, {'userId': 'user1', 'processId': 'p1', 'reportName': 'report1', 'threadId': '12335', 'some_other_keys': 'respective values.12335', 'another_key': 'another_value.12335','key1': 'key1_value.12335'}, {'processId': 'p1', 'userId': 'user1', 'reportName': 'report1', 'threadId': '12834', 'some_other_keys': 'respective values.12834','key2': 'key2_value.12834'}]
```

**Note:** different json lines have different set of keys.

In these lines 'processId': 'p1', 'userId': 'user1', 'reportName': 'report1' are same for all the lines and this is known to the programmer.

Objective:

1. write a function to create a single JSON line out of the above.
2. function arguments are

   1. list of matching keys i.e. `["processId","userId","reportName"]`
   2. the dictionary as mentioned above.

Output:

The expect output for the above input dictionary is as below, a single JSON record.

```
{"processId": "p1", "userId": "user1", "reportName": "report1", "threadId_0": "12234", "some_other_keys_0": "respective values.12234", "threadId_1": "12335", "some_other_keys_1": "respective values.12335", "another_key_1": "another_value.12335","key1_1": "key1_value.12335", "threadId_2": "12834", "some_other_keys_2": "respective values.12834","key2_2": "key2_value.12834"}
```

My current code looks like below:

```
def multijson_to_singlejson_matchingkey(list_json, list_keys):
    rec0 = {}
    for l in range(len(list_keys)):
        key0 = list_keys[l]
        value0 = list_json[0][key0]
        rec0[f'{key0}'] = value0
    rec = {}
    for i in range(len(list_json)):
        line = list_json[i]
        for j in range(len(list_keys)):
            del line[list_keys[j]]
        line_keys = list(line)
        for k in range(len(line_keys)):
            key_a = line_keys[k] + "_" + f"{i}"
            line[f'{key_a}'] = line[f'{line_keys[k]}']
            del line[f'{line_keys[k]}']
        rec = {**rec, **line}
    res = {}
    res = {**rec0, **rec}
    print(res)
    return res
```

But this is a function with 20 lines of code. I'm trying to **optimize the code** with less number of lines of code and making it more performance efficient. Need help with the available options for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the generation of `rec0` to a hopefully reasonably readable one-liner, and then loop over the list of input dictionaries to populate the rest, ignoring any keys that are in `list_keys` (although testing here equivalently against `rec0` as it is marginally faster):

```
def multi_to_single(list_json, list_keys):
    rec0 = dict((key0, list_json[0][key0]) for key0 in list_keys)
    res = rec0.copy()
    for i, dct in enumerate(list_json):
        for k, v in dct.items():
            if k not in rec0:
                res[f'{k}_{i}'] = v
    print(res)
    return res
```

This gives (with `pprint.pprint` here instead of `print` for ease of reading):

```
{'another_key_1': 'another_value.12335',
 'key1_1': 'key1_value.12335',
 'key2_2': 'key2_value.12834',
 'processId': 'p1',
 'reportName': 'report1',
 'some_other_keys_0': 'respective values.12234',
 'some_other_keys_1': 'respective values.12335',
 'some_other_keys_2': 'respective values.12834',
 'threadId_0': '12234',
 'threadId_1': '12335',
 'threadId_2': '12834',
 'userId': 'user1'}
```